# How to use Button as a control in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, gui-construction

I am trying to use `Button` as a controller in `Manipulate`.

I have done some thing like this:

```
Manipulate[
  p = Column[{Plot[Sin[x - n], {x, 0, 12.4}, ImageSize -> 500]}], 
  {n, 0, 1}, 
  Button["Export", Export["test.jpg", p]]]
```

Is there any better way to do this?

I am thinking of making something like this:

```
Manipulate[
  Column[{p = Plot[Sin[x - n], {x, 0, 12.4}, ImageSize -> 500], 
  If[x, Export["test.jpg", p]]}], 
  {n, 0, 1}, 
  {x, {False, True}}]
```

in which the controller `x` is represented by `Button` instead of a `Checkbox`.

How can I do that?

Comment: there is a button example in the docs `ref/Manipulate#163569372`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I would stay with your first example, but if you insist on a more loose coupling between the button and the `Export` expression, maybe something like the following:

```
filePath = FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[], "DeskTop", "test.jpg"}];
Manipulate[
  p = Plot[Sin[x - n], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, ImageSize -> 300];
  If[export, Export[filePath, p]; export = False];
  p,
  {n, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{export, False}, None},
  Button["Export", export = True]]
```

[image: manip]

Comment: There is x as Boolean, and also x in the plot range value (argument to Plot)?

Comment: @Nasser. They are not the same; they are in different scopes. Maybe bad naming, but I used the OP names.

Comment: Yes, I know, Plot localized the x, else it wont work, but I meant a different name would be better for readability and less confusing.  that is all.

Comment: @Nasser. I agree. I'll do an edit.

Comment: good descriptive name !

Comment: @Nasser, I meant different symbol. in fact they are treated differently in the code, but you are right I should have used different symbol to remove confusion.

Comment: @m_goldberg, thanks for the answer. I need this because in my real code there are calculations within the Export itself (the name is being calculated inside the code) so I thought it will not be good to put the calculations in the controllers area.

Comment: @Algohi You can put the calculations in the button action. You might have to add `Method -> "Queued"` in case it does not time-out if it takes too long. "Queued" method does not time out. But you can try and see which works best, the default (preemptive) or the `Queued` for your application.

Comment: @Nasser, I will check out your suggestion also. thanks.