# How to solve this PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I had a try at numerically solving the heat equation with a source term:
$$
\frac{{\partial x}}{{\partial t}} = D\frac{{{\partial ^2}x}}{{\partial {z^2}}} + c
$$

```
Manipulate[Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, t}, L0 = 1;
  pde = D[u[x, t], t] == d D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c ;
  bc = {D[u[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, u[L0, t] == 0};
  ic = u[x, 0] == 1 - x;(*made up IC*)pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0};
  solN = Quiet@
    NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], 
     u, {x, 0, L0}, {t, 0, t0}];
  Quiet@Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t0] /. solN], {x, 0, L0}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "u(x,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], {{d0, 0.1, "D"}, 
  0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, maxTime, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 200}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]
```

I messed up apparently because the bc2 is not doing what I want. Even if c=0 with time there is no diffusion.

**Answer**
It requires a NeumannValue, to impose a basal flux=0:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, t, \[CapitalGamma]},
   L0 = 1;
  pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
    d D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c + NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
  bc = u[L0, t] == 0;
  ic = u[x, 0] == 1 - x;(*made up IC*)pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0};
  solN = Quiet@
    NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], 
     u, {x, 0, L0}, {t, 0, t0}];
  Quiet@Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t0] /. solN], {x, 0, L0}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "u(x,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], {{d0, 0.1, "D"}, 
  0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, maxTime, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 200}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]
```

**How to plot u[x,t] at x==0 as a function of t?**

Tried:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, t, \[CapitalGamma]},
   L0 = 5;
  pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
    d D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c + NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
  bc = u[L0, t] == 0;
  ic = u[x, 0] == (L0 - x)/L0;(*made up IC*)pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0};
  solN = Quiet@
    NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], 
     u, {x, 0, L0}, {t, 0, t0}];
  Quiet@Plot[Evaluate[u[0, t0] /. solN], {t0, 0, 300}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "u(0,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], {{d0, 0.01, "D"},
   0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, maxTime, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 300}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]
```

**Write out the data for u[0,t]**

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, t, \[CapitalGamma]},
   L0 = 5;
  pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
    d D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c + NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
  bc = u[L0, t] == 0;
  ic = u[x, 0] == (L0 - x)/L0;(*made up IC*)pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0};
  solN = NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], 
    u, {x, 0, L0}, {t, 0, t0}];
(*data is GLOBAL so to access it from outside*)
data = Table[{t, Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN]}, {t, 0, t0, 0.1}];
  Quiet@Plot[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, t0}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "u(0,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], {{d0, 0.01, "D"},
   0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 1, "time"}, 0.1, maxTime, 0.1,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 300}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]


Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "data_table_test.csv", Flatten /@ data]
```

Comment: Hi @Dave, welcome to Mma.SE. To make the most of the site start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will help us to help you if you write an [excellent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please [edit] your question if you can improve it, in this case to show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code you have tried. Have you read the documentation for `NDSolve`? what have you tried?

Comment: Well, as a beginner, the first thing you need to learn is, get used to reading the document of _Mathematica_, which is well-written and suitable for self-learning. As to your problem, `NDSolve` should be able to handle it without difficulty.

Comment: @rhermans I had a try at solving something simpler, and updated the question

Comment: `because the bc2 is not doing what I want.` It not clear to me what you mean here. But Mathematica can solve this analytically and it has no problem. Below is an illustration. May be you could explain more that you think the problem is? btw, your Latex does not match the PDE.   may be you can correct that.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure what the problem is, as it seems to be to be working ok.

But here is a version that uses `DSolve` (since it can solve this PDE analytically, then I see no reason to use `NDSolve` in this case, but this can be easily be changed)

Added few buttons to make it easier to simulate. May be this will help you investigate the solution better.

[image]

First run this in separate cell to solve the PDE analytically.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == d*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c;
bc = {D[u[x, t], x] == 0 /. x -> 0, u[L, t] == 0};
ic = u[x, 0] == 1 - x;(*made up IC*)
sol = DSolve[{pde, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}];
sol = u[x, t] /. First@Activate[sol /. {Infinity -> 10, K[1] -> n}];
```

[image]

etc.. The Analytical solution is a series. 10 terms are used. You can use more terms if you want. But I think this is enough for these kinds of problems.

And now in new cell, run Manipulate to use the above solution over and over. No need to solve the PDE each time. Solve it only once.

```
Manipulate[Module[{pars, L0},
  L0 = 1;
  pars = {d -> d0, L -> L0, t -> t0, c -> c0};
  If[state == "running",
   If [t0 < maxTime,
    t0 += 0.1; tick = Not[tick],
    t0 = 0
    ]
   ];
  Grid[{{Row[{"Time ", t0}]},
    {
     Quiet@Plot[sol /. pars, {x, 0, L0},
       PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, maxU}},
       GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
       PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"x", "u(x,t)"},
       BaseStyle -> 12,
       ImageSize -> 300]
     }}, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
  ],
 Grid[{
   {Button["Run", {state = "running"}, ImageSize -> 100],
    Button["Stop", {state = "stopped"}, ImageSize -> 100],
    Button[
     "Reset", {state = "stopped"; t0 = 0; c0 = 0; d0 = 0.1; 
      tick = Not[tick]}, ImageSize -> 100]
    }
   }
  ],
 {{d0, 0.1, "Diffusion"}, 0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{maxU, 1, "max U"}, 1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{maxTime, 20}, None},
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{t0, 0}, None},
 {{state, "stopped"}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, maxU, tick, state, t0}
 ]
```

> How do I plot the u[x,0] = f(t) ? Which should look like an
> exponential decay for c=0, using NDsolve? I tried using the
> formulation I had initially but that plots u at x=0 as a straight line
> at all times

That is because your are plotting it at t=0 all the time!  You are mixing symbols. You are doing  `Plot[Evaluate[u[0, t0] /. solN]`  but `t0` is your control variable. Which is set to start at `0`. That is why it does not change. Basically, you were doing this

```
Plot[1,{t0,0,300}]
```

Because `Evaluate[u[0, t0] /. solN` is `1`

Try

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, t, \[CapitalGamma]},
  L0 = 5;
  pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
    d D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c + NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
  bc = u[L0, t] == 0;
  ic = u[x, 0] == (L0 - x)/L0;(*made up IC*)
  pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0};
  solN = NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], 
    u, {x, 0, L0}, {t, 0, t0}];
  Quiet@Plot[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, t0},
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}},
    GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray,
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "u(0,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]
  ],
 {{d0, 0.01, "D"}, 0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{t0, 1, "time"}, 0.1, maxTime, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{maxTime, 300}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}
 ]
```

And you should not have `t0` start at zero. Because Plot will complain if you have zero for length of plot. Try to make it little above zero.

[image]

**Update to answer comment**

> How do I save the data in a csv? I tried this, but I cannot place them
> in the Manipulate data = Table[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, 300,
> 0.1}]; Export["data_table_test.csv", data];

@Dave You are trying to use the solution and `t0` from outside Manipulate. It does not "see" them, since `solN` is local to a module inside Manipulate.   One way to work around this, is to save to the global `data` from inside Manipulate. Then in a new cell, you can now export it. But do not do `Table[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, 300,0.1}]` from OUTSIDE, as it will not work and do not make `data` local variable to Manipulate.

Like this

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, t, \[CapitalGamma]},
   L0 = 5;
  pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
    d * D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c + NeumannValue[0, x == 0];
  bc = u[L0, t] == 0;
  ic = u[x, 0] == (L0 - x)/L0;(*made up IC*)
  pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0};
  solN = NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], 
    u, {x, 0, L0}, {t, 0, t0}];
  (*data is GLOBAL so to access it from outside*)
  data = Table[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, t0, 0.1}];
  Quiet@Plot[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, t0}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "u(0,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], {{d0, 0.01, "D"},
   0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 
  0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 1, "time"}, 0.1, maxTime, 0.1,
   Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 300}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]
```

And now in a new cell, you can use `data`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And can now do anything you want with it. Notice each time you do something with Manipulate, the variable `data` will be updated automatically.

**Update to answer comment**

> Can you show an example of this "button"?

Here is a simple example. The data is saved only when you click on the button. This can be more efficient than saving it each time.

```
Manipulate[Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, t}, 
  L0 = 5; 
  pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
    d*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c + NeumannValue[0, x == 0]; 
  bc = u[L0, t] == 0; 
  ic = u[x, 0] == (L0 - x)/L0; 
  pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0}; 
  solN = NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], 
    u, {x, 0, L0}, {t, 0, t0}]; 
  
  If[needToSaveData, 
   data = Table[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, t0, 0.1}]; 
   needToSaveData = False]; 
  
  Quiet[Plot[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, t0}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.5}}, 
    GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
    PlotStyle -> Red, AxesLabel -> {"t", "u(0,t)"}, 
    BaseStyle -> 12]]
  ], 
 
 {{d0, 0.01, "D"}, 0.001, 1, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
   {{t0, 1, "time"}, 0.1, maxTime, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{maxTime, 300}, None}, {{needToSaveData, True}, None}, 
   Grid[{{Button[
     Text[Style["save data", 12]], {needToSaveData = True}, 
     ImageSize -> {80, 40}]}}], 
 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0, needToSaveData}
 
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's awesome. Will this method also work if some terms are time-dependent? I would like D and c to be time-dependent in the next step

Comment: @Dave probably not using `DSolve` if the coefficients are time dependent as then analytical solution might not be possible so have to go back to `NDSolve`

Comment: How do I plot the u[x,0] = f(t) ? Which should look like an exponential decay for c=0, using NDsolve? I tried using the formulation I had initially but that plots u at x=0 as a straight line at all times; @Nasser

Comment: @Dave added note.

Comment: thanks a lot; learning so much thanks to those solutions you are sharing; @Nasser

Comment: How do I save the data in a csv? I tried this, but I cannot place them in the Manipulate                                                                 
data = Table[Evaluate[u[0, t] /. solN], {t, 0, 300, 0.1}];
Export["data_table_test.csv", data]; @Nasser

Comment: @Dave  when you write `{t, 0, 300, 0.1}` you need to first make sure your `solN` was computed for up to `300`, else you will get error as it will do extrapolation instead of interpolation. Better do `{t, 0, t0, 0.1}` where `t0` is your current maximum you did NDSolve on.

Comment: please see edit in main post, it shows an error @Nasser

Comment: @Dave added a note.

Comment: great, works perfecly @Nasser

Comment: @Dave  one improvement you can make, if you do not want to save the data each time you move the slider, if you find this slows things, is to add a button, which you click on, and only then you save the data.

Comment: Can you show an example of this "button"? And how to add other columns to the table? Trying data = Table[{t, u[0, t]} /. solN, {t, 0, t0, 0.1}];  makes the data written as: 0 {109872.}
0.1 {108726.19814894235}
0.2 {108162.72681689088}
0.3 {107757.74129978601}
0.4 {107426.71337536997}
0.5 {107143.50085999009}
0.6 {106891.50530140719}
I tried many version, the brakets {} are always there ; @Nasser

Comment: @Dave An example of button in Manipulate is something like in this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50685/how-to-use-button-as-a-control-in-manipulate there are also examples in the documentation for Button.

Comment: @Dave I tried `data = Table[{t, u[0, t]} /. solN, {t, 0, t0, 0.1}];` and it works for me.  Here is a screen shot    ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETJKd.png)   I get `{{1.}, {0.994519}, {0.990774}, {0.987991}, {0.985804}, {0.983981}, 
{0.982397}, {0.980975}, {0.979663}, {0.978436}, {0.977275}}` as you see from the screen shot. So you have done something else or changed something.

Comment: @Dave added example of button

Comment: Thanks, I had the data table correct indeed, but I did not know of the need to "Flatten". All good now. Thanks for adding the button; @Nasser

Answer (score 1):

You should not ignore error messages like `NDSolve::ibcinc: Warning: Boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent. >>`  with `Quiet`  .

Change the derivative in bc to  `-E^(-t*10000)`, which is anytime very close to zero exept for t==0 and your first attempt works for me.

```
Manipulate[Module[{d, c, solN, pars, L0, pde, ic, bc, x, u, 
   t}, L0 = 1; pde = D[u[x, t], t] == 
      d*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] + c; 
  bc = {Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == -E^((-t)*10000), 
      u[L0, t] == 0}; ic = u[x, 0] == 1 - x; 
  pars = {d -> d0, c -> c0}; 
  solN = NDSolve[Evaluate[{pde, ic, bc} /. pars], u, 
      {x, 0, L0}, {t, 0, t0}]; 
  Plot[Evaluate[u[x, t0] /. solN], {x, 0, L0}, 
    PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "u(x,t)"}, BaseStyle -> 12]], 
 {{d0, 0.1, "D"}, 0.001, 1, 0.001, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{c0, 0, "c"}, 0, 10, 0.01, 
 Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{t0, 0, "time"}, 0, maxTime, 
 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{maxTime, 200}, None}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {d0, c0, t0}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Akku14 but your sol gives something a bit different. For instance at t=300 u[0,300] is 0.02 (t=5000, u[0,t] = 0.019; and with the NeumannValue bc u[0,300]=5E-4;